# Efficient algorithm for finding a vector to maximize the number of positive dot products with a given set (finding the maximum overlap of half-spaces)

Tags: algorithms, optimization, linear-algebra, mathematical-programming

I have a large set $\mathbf{V}$ of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^d\setminus\{\mathbf{0}\}$ and need to find a vector $\mathbf{u}$ that maximizes $\sum_{\mathbf{v}\in\mathbf{V}}\mathbf{1}_{\mathbf{u}\cdot\mathbf{v}>0}$, which is to say the count of vectors in $\mathbf{V}$ that have a positive dot product with $\mathbf{u}$. Alternatively, one could also phrase this problem as finding a maximum subset of the half-spaces defined by the elements of $\mathbf{V}$ such that the intersection of those half-spaces is nonempty. I am wondering if an efficient algorithm for this problem is known.

Just to rule out an obvious idea, normalizing the vectors in $\mathbf{V}$ and taking their average does not solve the problem. In particular, even in two dimensions a normalized set like $\mathbf{V}=\left\{\left(1, 0\vphantom{\frac{0}{0}}\right)\!, \left(-\frac{5}{13}, \frac{12}{13}\right)\!, \left(-\frac{5}{13}, -\frac{12}{13}\right)\right\}$ would have average $\left(\frac{1}{13},0\right)$, which only has a positive dot product with $\left(1, 0\vphantom{\frac{0}{0}}\right)$, whereas an alternative like $\left(-1, 0\vphantom{\frac{0}{0}}\right)$ has a positive dot product with both $\left(-\frac{5}{13}, \frac{12}{13}\right)$ and $\left(-\frac{5}{13}, -\frac{12}{13}\right)$.

A correct but slow algorithm would be to consider all size-$(d-1)$ subsets of $\mathbf{V}$, use each subset to construct a candidate vector orthogonal to everything in the subset, and then keep whichever of these candidates maximizes the count. But the run time of that design has $d$ in an exponent, so it scales poorly.  Is there something better?

Context that I don't think affects the answer, but I will include anyway in case I am wrong, and it is relevant:

- In this particular case, I actually have $\mathbf{V}\in\mathbb{Z}^d\setminus\{\mathbf{0}\}$, so the components are in fact integers.
- For the particular application, I would be very surprised if the answer $\mathbf{u}$ did not have all positive components, though I still expect vectors in $\mathbf{V}$ to have components with mixed signs.
- I also suspect that the subspace of solutions will be connected, and it would be nice to compute a $\mathbf{u}$ that is in the middle of this space so that its quality isn't super sensitive to issues with precision, rounding, etc. later on.

Comment: If you are happy with approximations, this might be useful: https://arxiv.org/abs/2106.13851

Comment: @Tassle Could you turn that into an answer? Their algorithm considers half-spaces with boundaries away from the origin, which is different than my question, but as I look more closely, I think it could still be adapted to that restriction. So I will probably take this route if no efficient exact solution turns up.

Comment: I suspect your problem is NP-hard, as it is basically finding a one-class SVM with 0-1 loss, and it is apparently known that optimizing for a (two-class) SVM with 0-1 loss is NP-hard (though I don't know the proof off-hand).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you are describing a problem that is almost identical to the optimization problem in [Support Vector Machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine). The only difference is that in your case the separating plane is not offset from the origin, i.e. $b=0$. If a $u$ exists that makes all dot products positive, you could solve the following [convex optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_optimization) problem:

$$
\begin{matrix}
\mathcal{minimize}_u && 0 \\
\mathcal{subject} \; to && V^Tu \ge 1
\end{matrix}
$$

If violations are possible, you could introduce a slack/error vector $e$ solve the following problem:

$$
\begin{matrix}
\mathcal{minimize}_{u,e} && \max_i{e_i} \\
\mathcal{subject} \; to && V^Tu \ge 1-e \\&& e \ge 0
\end{matrix}
$$

Which, again, is a convex optimization problem. There many open-source convex solvers available, like [CVXOPT](https://cvxopt.org/) and [CVXPY](https://www.cvxpy.org/) for Python.

Comment: Great connection!  I think it's very close, but not quite correct, I think.  It looks to me like the question is related but different from the standard SVM problem.  The problem as stated in the question is effectively asks us to  minimize the 0-1 loss, whereas your optimization formulation minimizes the hinge loss.  Consequently solving the optimization problem in this answer doesn't (necessarily) yield the optimal solution to the problem in the question.

Comment: To elaborate on @D.W.'s comment above, unfortunately, the vector minimizing $e$ might be arbitrarily bad. For instance, when one vector in $\mathbf{V}$ is $(1,0,\ldots,0)$, and the other vectors are all $(-\epsilon,\ldots)$ in some symmetric arrangement, the formulation in this answer has its optimum at $(1,0,\ldots,0)$, which gives $e=\epsilon$, but its count of positive dot products would only be $1$ instead of the true optimum, $\left\lvert V\right\rvert-1$. And the likelihood of such problems appearing grows with increasing $d$. Still, I appreciate the thought—it was a good idea.

Comment: I am out of my depth here, but I believe it does minimize the 0-1 loss. It's hidden in the boundary constraints (BC). Note that the BC are $\ge 1$ not $\ge 0$. In the counterexample given, $(V^Tu)_2$ would be $-\epsilon$ which would be much less than $1 - e_2 \approx 1$. That would be a massive boundary violation. See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/327807/why-hinge-loss-is-equivalent-to-0-1-loss-in-svm). P.S.: The formulation of my convex optimization problem might be off.

Comment: Can you [edit] your answer to add a proof of correctness for the second optimization formulation, i.e., explain why it finds the optimal solution to the original problem?  I don't understand the explanation in your comment.  To me it looks wrong.  The optimal solution to the original problem might have $v^T u$ be extremely negative for some $v$, in which case you have to take some $e_i$ be extremely large; but there might be another solution that is worse by the original problem's metric, but has a smaller value for all $e_i$'s.

Comment: But we minimize $\max_i{e_i}$ so large $e_i$ will be rejected. And the beauty of convex optimization is that we can reliably find the global minimum (in fact, there are no local minima).

I will try to put together a proof, but as I said: I am out of my depth. It will take me a little time to brush up my SVM and convex optimization knowledge.

Comment: Oh I see, I did not write down the proper SVM objective function. I will correct it as soon as I get to reading up on it again.